# List<String> not saving after loop

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find out why my *dataItems* `List<List<string>>` isn't saving after the loop. When I debug it it's adding to the *dataItemsList* `List<string>` just fine with 3 values each for and 6 iteration (as expected).

As soon as it leaves the for loop it's just 6 null Lists.

```
            List<List<string>> dataItems = new List<List<string>>();
            List<string> dataItemsList = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; dataReader.Read(); i++)
            {
                int j = 0;
                for (j = 0; j < dataReader.FieldCount; j++)
                {
                    dataItemsList.Add(dataReader[j].ToString());
                }
                dataItems.Add(dataItemsList);
                dataItemsList.Clear();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(dataItems);
```

There's more code but I'm hoping that it's something more local given that the values are being assigned within the loop but the variables are declared outside.

Comment: Why just not to debug and figure it out whats wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are clearing the list! (`dataItemsList.Clear();`)

Instead of clearing the list, you probably want to create a new instance:

```
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    List<string> dataItemsList = new List<string>();

    for (int j = 0; j < dataReader.FieldCount; j++)
    {
        dataItemsList.Add(dataReader[j].ToString());
    }

    dataItems.Add(dataItemsList);
}

Console.WriteLine(dataItems);
```

Comment: You can't "save" anything. It are just lists in memory and that list is cleared. Clearly. @WhatsThePoint

Comment: No, `dataItems` adds just a reference to the `dataItemsList`. Clear will remove all data from this list, and that is reflected in `dataItems` too

Comment: @WhatsThePoint No, because the reference `dataItemsList` still points to the list that was added.

Comment: @theHeavyDoc Exactly, that's why you need to create a completely new instance each time

Comment: *so dataItems should keep the values*. It does. It keeps the reference to the added list. Then that list is cleared.

Comment: In your code, there is just one instance of a list, which gets cleared and filled over and over again. My code creates a new list each and every time, and has a clear scope.

Comment: Boom, that did the trick. Deleted early messages as they were contextually irrelevant by the time I had finished typing :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a misunderstanding of how reference types work in C#.

When you call `dataItems.Add(dataItemsList)` what you are doing is add a new reference (pointer to memory heap) to where the `dataItemsList` exists. If you then call `Clear()`, you are modifying the collections contents and that is the same thing `dataItems[0]` points to. When you then repeat the loop, you again add to the same instance and clear it again. In the end you will have a collection of pointers to the one single `dataItemsList` which will end up empty.

That's why you have to instantiate a new instance (create new list in memory heap) at the beginning of the loop by calling `List<string> dataItemsList = new List<string>();` and you don't need to `Clear` it in the end.

It is very helpful to imagine reference types as pointers (arrows) that just point to a location. They don't contain data directly and assigning them does not copy anything, it just makes the arrow point to a particular memory address.

Comment: For me it is easier to imagine that the reference type objects are just objects, which **values** are "references" to real objects in heap.

Comment: Or like that, but that notion may be confusing if you are new to object oriented world...

Comment: Probably, for me it was easier that way in the beginning, well, maybe it's just me. :)